# How to pass current logged in users pk in django URLs?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

So I have this detailview of Profile model (extended from django user model [onetoone])

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
     model = Profile     
    fields = [
             "user",
             "bio",
             "fav_music_genre",
             "fav_Book_genre",
             "fav_movie_genre",
         ]
     success_url ="/home/all"
```

in urls

```
   path('ProfileUpdate/<pk>',ProfileUpdate.as_view(),name="ProfileUpdate"),
```

Now I wanna pass current logged in users pk in this path. I tried through template but its taking 1 by default. Is there any way by which I can put the current logged in users pk straight into the path in urls.py ?

```
<a href="{% url 'app:ProfileUpdate' user.pk %}">Change</a>
```

Any idea how can i approach this???

Comment: The request object has a reference to the logged in user.
You can use {{request.user.pk}} in your template.

Comment: @crystalAhmet did this `{% url 'app:ProfileUpdate' request.user.pk %}` but its messing it up like. I have four user its returning pk value like this : ayat-3(real pk 2), jake-5(real 4), ross-6(real 1), amanda-1(real 3)

Comment: answer is updated check now

Comment: @Mahammadhusain did exactly what your updated solution suggested. its messing up pk value I have four user its returning pk value like this : ayat-3(real pk 2), jake-5(real 4), ross-6(real 1), amanda-1(real 3)

Comment: Can you use {{request.user.id}} instead, or is there an specifically defined primary key field.
But: as I don't know, what the exact idea is, I'm not sure, if the view needs the ID (PK) of the Profile model instance anyway, and not the User ID. ???

Comment: It only takes pk or slug

Answer (score 0):

You can pass logged in user id like this...

#### urls.py

```
path('<int:pk>/ProfileUpdate/',ProfileUpdate.as_view(),name="ProfileUpdate")
```

#### HTML

```
<a href="{% url 'app:ProfileUpdate' request.user.pk %}">Change</a>
```

Comment: its showing this error "Generic detail view ProfileUpdate must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf."

Comment: did this `{% url 'app:ProfileUpdate' request.user.pk %}` but its messing it up like. I have four user its returning pk value like this : ayat-3(real pk 2), jake-5(real 4), ross-6(real 1), amanda-1(real 3)

Comment: change URL pattern in urls.py, answer is updated

Comment: its mixing up pk values. I have four registered user. its giving wrong pk values like [ayat,3(dcl], [dcl,1(rohan)}, [kusum,5(no user in this pk)], [rohan,6(no user)]

Comment: plz send me repo link

Comment: https://github.com/ayat1041/theirlist-website-night/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me the reason was like that: when I used `request.user.pk` in url tag - I got the pk from the User table, not from  the Profile table. So if you want to obtain the info from Profile table - you need to filter in it using the ForeignKey that you used while created Profile Model.